# Suppose f is twice differentiable, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that $\exists x \in [0;1]: |f''(x)| > 4$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is exercise 39 in Chapter 11 of Calculus by Spivak.

Suppose f is twice differentiable, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that $\exists x \in [0;1]: |f''(x)| > 4$

---

So part $(a)$ only requires you to prove $|f''(x)| \geq 4$, which can be handled.

Here's how i do it:
Let's assume that $f''(x) < 4$ on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$ and $f''(x) > -4$ on $[\frac{1}{2};1]$.
Now:
$$\forall x\in (0;\frac{1}{2}]: \exists x_0\in(0;x): f''(x_0) = \frac{f'(x) -f'(0)}{x-0} < 4 $$. Or: $f'(x) <4x,\forall x\in(0;\frac{1}{2}]$
Consider $g(x) = f(x) - 2x^2$.
So, $g'(x) = f'(x) - 4x$, which is $\leq 0$ and takes zero only once on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$. We conclude that $g$ is decreasing on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$. Therefore, $g(x) < g(0) = 0$. Or: $f(x) < 2x^2$. Choosing $x=\frac{1}{2},$ we have: $f(\frac{1}{2}) < \frac{1}{2}$.

In addition to that, consider $g(x) = 1- f(1-x)$ on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$, we have the same thing: $g(\frac{1}{2}) < \frac{1}{2}$, or: $f(\frac{1}{2}) > \frac{1}{2}$
So, $|f|$ must be $\geq 4$ at some point in one of the invervals
However, it goes tricky when it comes to prove $|f''(x)| > 4$.
Let's assume that $f′′(x)\leq 4$ on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$ and $f′′(x)\geq −4$ on $[\frac{1}{2};1] (*)$. Three cases to be considered.
**Case 1**:

$f''$ constantly takes the value of $4$ and $-4$ respectively on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2};1]$
This is absurd since $f''(\frac{1}{2})  = 4 = -4$

**Case 2**: There exists some $x$ in $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$ that $f''(x) < 4$
**Case 3**: There exists some $x$ in $[\frac{1}{2};1]$ that $f''(x) > -4$

We will try to exclude **case 2** and **case 3** will be trivial.
The idea is to show: $f(\frac{1}{2}) < \frac{1}{2}$ just like part $(a)$ and $f(\frac{1}{2}) \geq \frac{1}{2}$. It's the idea from the answer book and i'm trying to follow it.

[image]

$f'(x) \leq 4x,\forall x\in[0;\frac{1}{2}]$ by $(*)$, Mean value theorem and the fact that $f'(0) = 0$ $(**)$

If we had $f'(x) = 4x, \forall 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ then clearly $f''(x) = 4, \forall 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}$, which is absurd due the condition of **case 2**. So:
$$\exists x_0 \in (0;\frac{1}{2}]: f'(x_0) < 4x_0$$. And $\forall \frac{1}{2} \geq x>x_0$: Applying Mean-value theorem into $[x_0;x]$, we have: $$\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x-x_0}\leq 4$$ or: $f'(x) - 4x \leq f'(x_0) - 4x_0 <0 $. Hence: "$f'(x) < 4x$ for larger x in $(0;\frac{1}{2}]$". But this time, when we consider $g(x) = f(x) - 2x^2$, we have nothing like $g(0)$ to compare with! We do have $(**)$ but the number of zeros might be infinite, so we can't know whether f is decreasing! I'm trying to extend the fact somehow to $[0;x_0)$. I'd like to hear your opinions on how to proceed.

Comment: I think you can keep using your $g(x) = f(x) - 2x^2$. $g = 0$ on $[0,x_0]$, but to the right of $x_0$, $g' < 0$ which implies $g(1/2) < 0.$

Comment: As an aside: IMO this is one of the most "broken" problems in the book. The Answer Book for the third edition contains some errors that suggest Spivak's original intent was for a much simpler problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $|f''(x)| \le 4$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Using the mean-value theorem we determine an upper bound for $f'$: On the interval $[0, 1/2]$ we have
$$
 f'(x) = \underbrace{f'(0)}_{=0} + (x-0) \underbrace{f''(c)}_{\le 4} \le 4x
$$
and on the interval $[1/2, 1]$ we have
$$
 f'(x) = \underbrace{f'(1)}_{=0} + (x-1) \underbrace{f''(d)}_{\ge -4} \le -4(x-1) = 4(1-x) \, .
$$
So we have
$$ \tag{*}
 f'(x) \le \begin{cases}
 4x & \text{ for } 0 \le x \le 1/2 \, ,\\
 4(1-x) & \text{ for } 1/2 \le x \le 1  \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$ 
1 = f(1) - f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(x) \, dx \underset{(**)}{\le} \int_0^{1/2} 4x \, dx + 
\int_{1/2}^1 4(1-x) \, dx = \frac 12  + \frac 12 = 1
$$
so that equality holds at $(**)$. Since $f'$ is continuous, it follows that equality holds in $(*)$ for every $x \in [0, 1]$.

But then $f''(1/2)$ does not exist, contrary to the assumption that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: This problem comes several chapters before integration is introduced, though OP doesn't seem to mind that :)

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Proof**

Here, I'll restrict the discussion to the left subinterval $[0,1/2]$.

Much of this was already done by @MathematicsBeginner, but I thought it might be useful to include anyway, for the sake of clarity.

Let's begin by proving some useful lemmas.

**Lemma 1:**

If $f''(x) \leq 4$ for all $x$ on $[0,1/2]$, then $f'(x)\leq 4x$.

**Lemma 1 Proof:**

Suppose $f'' \leq 4$ on $[0,1/2]$. Suppose $x$ is in the interval $(0,1/2]$.
Applying MVT to the points $0$ and $x$ we have
$$\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x - 0} = f''(y),$$
for some $y$ in $(0,x)$.
So,
\begin{align}
\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x - 0} = f''(y) &\leq 4, \\
\frac{f'(x)}{x} &\leq 4, \\
f'(x) &\leq 4x.
\end{align}

Thus, we see $f'(x) \leq 4x$ on $(0,1/2]$. We are also given $f'(0) = 0 = 4\cdot 0$, so we can extend the statement across the whole interval.
$$\blacksquare$$

**Lemma 2:**

If $f''(x_0) < 4$ for $x_0$ on $[0,1/2)$, then $f'(x) < 4x$ for all $x$ on some interval to the right of $x_0$.

**Lemma 2 Proof:**
If $f''(x_0) < 4$ then we can find some $x$'s sufficiently close to $x_0$ such that $\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x - x_0} < 4$.

Putting it more formally: For $\varepsilon = \frac{4 - f''(x_0)}{2} > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if

$$x_0 < x < x_0 + \delta \text{, then } \left|\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f''(x_0) \right| < \varepsilon,$$
\begin{align}
\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x - x_0} &< f''(x_0) + \varepsilon, \\
\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x - x_0} &< \frac{4 + f''(x_0)}{2} < 4, \\
f'(x) - f'(x_0) &< 4x - 4x_0, \\
f'(x) &< 4x + f'(x_0) - 4x_0. 
\end{align}
Now, from lemma 1 we have $f'(x_0) - 4x_0 \leq 0$, so
$$f'(x) < 4x + f'(x_0) - 4x_0 \leq 4x,$$
$$f'(x) < 4x.$$
$$\blacksquare$$
Please forgive the formalism. The takeaway here is that, given the constraint of $f'' \leq 4$ on the interval $[0,1/2]$, if there is a single point $x_0$ on $[0,1/2)$ with $f''(x_0) < 4$, then some subinterval of points directly to the right of $x_0$ will have $f'(x) < 4x$.

**Lemma 3:**
(This third lemma isn't really needed for the proof, but I think it's worth including.)

If there is any $x_0$ on $[0,1/2)$ with $f'(x_0) < 4x_0$, then $f'(x) < 4x$ for all $x > x_0$.

**Lemma 3 Proof:**
Suppose there is some $x_0$ on $[0,1/2)$ with $f'(x_0) < 4x_0$.

For $x > x_0$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{f'(x) - f'(x_0)}{x - x_0} &\leq 4, \\
f'(x) - f'(x_0) &\leq 4x - 4x_0, \\
f'(x) &\leq 4x - 4x_0 + f'(x_0).
\end{align}

We know $-4x_0 + f'(x_0) < 0$, so

$$f'(x) < 4x.$$
$$\blacksquare$$

**Case 2**

With our lemmas in hand, we return to case 2 in the problem.

Defining $g$ as before
$$g(x) = f(x) - 2x^2,$$
we see that $g$ is a continuous function, with $g(0) = 0$. Furthermore,
$$g'(x) = f'(x) - 4x.$$

From lemma 1, we know $f'(x) - 4x \leq 0$, which means $g' \leq 0$: $g$ is **a nonincreasing function**, i.e. for $a < b$, $g(a) \geq g(b)$.

In case 2 we suppose that $f'' = 4$ for some points in $[0,1/2]$ and $f'' < 4$ for others. From lemmas 2 and 3 we see that if $f''(x_0) < 4$ for any $x_0$ on the interval $[0,1/2)$, then $f'(x) < 4x$ for all $x > x_0$.

Given such an $x_0$, we have on $(x_0,1/2]$,
$$g'(x) = f'(x) - 4x < 0,$$
which implies $g$ is *decreasing* on $(x_0, 1/2]$.

Putting this all together, if there is any point $x_0$ in $[0,1/2)$ with $f'' < 4$, we have
\begin{align}
g(0) &\geq g(x_0) > g(1/2), \\
0 &> g(1/2), \\
0 &> f(1/2) - 2\cdot(1/2)^2, \\
1/2 &> f(1/2).
\end{align}
$$\blacksquare$$

To reiterate a point I made in the comments, the problem, as a whole, shows that *if* a function $f$ satisfies the given constraints, it must have $|f''(x)| > 4$ for some $x$ somewhere on $[0,1]$.

However, such a function *may not exist*. Finding an $f$ that actually works, I think is a matter of solving some differential equations, and is certainly beyond the scope of Spivak's chapter 11.

**Original (wrong) proof**

For your case 2, by assumption we have

- $f''(x) \leq 4$ for all $x$ in $[0,1/2]$
- $f''(x) = 4$ for all $x$ in $(0,x_0)$
- $f''(x_0) < 4$
- $f'(0) = 0$
- $f(0) = 0$

Just as you did previously, we can apply MVT to points in $(0,x_0)$ to see
\begin{align}
\frac {f'(x) - f'(0)}{x - 0} &= 4, \\
\frac{f'(x)}{x} &= 4, \\
f'(x) &= 4x.
\end{align}

Using this, together with the function $g$ as you defined it, we see that on $[0,x_0]$ we have
\begin{align}
g(x) &= f(x) - 2x^2, \\
g'(x) &= f'(x) - 4x, \\
g'(x) &= 0.
\end{align}

So, $g$ is constant on $[0,x_0]$. Therefore, $g(x_0) = g(0)=0$ (i.e. $f(x_0) = 2x_0^2).$

To the right of $x_0$ however, as you discussed, we must have $f'(x) < 4x$.

For the region $(x_0,1/2)$ we have
\begin{align}
g'(x) &= f'(x) - 4x, \\ 
&< 0.
\end{align}

$g(x_0) = 0$ and $g$ decreasing on $(x_0, 1/2)$ imply that $g$ is negative to the right of $x_0$, including the point $1/2$. (Apply the MVT to the interval $[x_0, 1/2]$).

Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
g(1/2) &< 0, \\
g(1/2) = f(1/2) - 2(1/2)^2 &< 0, \\
f(1/2) &< 1/2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! You have a great point: $g$ is constant on $[0;x_0]$ but i don't see why $f''(x) = 4, \forall x \in (0;x_0)$. Could you elaborate that more?

Comment: The case 2 assumption is that $x_0$ is the first point on $(0,1/2)$ where $f'' < 0$ (implying $f'' = 4$ on $[0,x_0)$.

Comment: To summarize: you show first that $|f''| < 4$ leads to a contradiction (the "particle" doesn't reach the full distance in time). Then you show $|f''| = 4$ also leads to a contradiction (where $f''(1/2)$ does not exist.) Finally you show $|f''| \leq 4$ also doesn't work (this includes the previous two cases, as well as the case of $|f''| = 4$ for some part of the interval and $< 4$ for the other part. All put together, the only remaining option is that $|f''| > 4$ somewhere.

Comment: Of course it's possible for all of those former cases to be false, and also for the case with $|f''| > 4$ somewhere, to *also* be false. Spivak never provides us with a *positive case* in the published solution. It's not too hard to come up with one, but that's a little past the scope of the chapter. Because of the structure of this problem, I think his proof by contradiction is a bit lacking. Unlike other proofs by contradiction, I don't know that it's safe for the reader here to assume the solution is either $|f''| \leq 4$ or not. There might not be a solution.

Comment: (Contrast this with other proofs by contradiction, for example, the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is not rational. Notice the difference there, where surely if a number is not rational, it is irrational.)

Comment: What we're really proving here is, *if* there is a solution, it will require that somewhere in the interval, $|f''| > 4$. And *this* is based on the assumption that $|f''| > 4$ doesn't itself lead to any contradictions (an assumption which Spivak's solution conspicuously avoids investigating).

Answer (score 1):

So, consider this set:
$$ A=  \{x\in (0;\frac{1}{2}]|f'(x) -4x<0\}$$
We know this set isn't empty since $\exists x_0 \in (0;\frac{1}{2}]: f'(x_0) < 4x_0$. Furthermore, $A$ bounded below by $0$. So we must have: $\exists \alpha \geq 0 = infA$.
This means: $\forall \epsilon>0: \exists x_0 \in A: 0<x-\alpha<\epsilon$.
Therefore:
If $\alpha = 0$ then for every such $x_0$, we can prove: $\forall x\in(x_0;\frac{1}{2}]: f'(x) <4x$. Or: $f'(x) -4x$ must $<$ $0$ on $(0;\frac{1}{2}]$, and consequently on $[0;\frac{1}{2}]$, we have: $g(0) > g(\frac{1}{2})$ since $g$ is decreasing.
Else, $\alpha >0$, similarly, we have: $g$ is decreasing on $[\alpha;\frac{1}{2}]$ but remains constant on $[0;\alpha)$.

Comment: What do you think, @MartinR ?

Comment: What do you think, @Ben ?

Comment: I see that I've confused things in my answer. I was using $x_0$ as the first point in $[0,1/2]$ with $f''(x_0) < 4$, which is different that your $x_0$, which is a point with $f'(x_0) < 4x_0$.

Comment: Ah! I see now that my answer was woefully incomplete. My assumption for case 2 that there is a smallest $x_0$ with $f''(x_0) < 4$ is wrong, as you tried to point out to me!

Comment: I added a revised proof to my answer. Hopefully this one is better! Sorry about the confusion. I didn't understand the problem as well as I thought I did!

Comment: I think my revised approach is basically equivalent to your approach looking at $\inf A$.